# Moment Generating Function from Piecewise Constant CDF?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to find the moment generating function from a piecewise CDF that has constant values:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } x<0, \\ 
\frac14, & \text{if } 0\le x<2,\\
\frac34, & \text{if } 2\le x<4,\\
1, & \text{if } x \ge 4.\\\end{cases}$$

But if I take the derivative of this to get the pdf from which I can calculate expected value, I would get $0$, since the cumulative distribution function is constant. So wold the mgf just be $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the CDF is piecewise constant, the distribution is a discrete distribution.

Let me write out the PMF:

$$P(X=0)=\frac14, P(X=2)=\frac34-\frac14, P(X=4)=1-\frac34$$

Can you write down the MGF now?

Comment: I thought this might be the case. But if I integrate the part from 4 to infinity the integral would not converge? Also, isn't it continuous on the parts where the distribution is constant? Thanks

Comment: integrate? MGF over a discrete distribution just involve summation. "continous" function and "continuous" random variable means different thing.

Comment: Oh, I thought because it can take on any value between say 0 and 2 I would integrate 1/4 from 0 to 2. But in either case if I were to sum from 4 to infinity using the probability 1-(3/4) = (1/4), it would still not converge? Or do I not need to sum to infinity? I'm a little confused. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't take any value between $0$ and $2$. Perhaps first try to go from PMF to construct the CDF?  You only need to sum over the support which are just $0, 2$, and $4$.

Comment: Exercise that might help you in understanding what is going on, given that $P(Y=0)=1-p$ and $P(Y=1)=p$, write down the CDF and MGF.

Comment: I see now, thanks!